# XPath to get all child elements except one with specific name?

Tags: xml, xpath, element

How do I target all elements in a document **except** a particular element name?

For example I want to exclude the `terminate` elements. They can occur throughout the document.

```
 <root>
     <terminate attr="1" />
     <other>
         The brown fox jumps over the fence. 
         <terminate>
            <b>stuff</b>
         </terminate>
     </other>
 </root>
```

I've tried using the `not(..)` operator without success likely because I'm using it wrong.

And frankly trying to Google 'not' is tough!

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The following xpath should work

```
/root/*[not(self::terminate)]
```

Also, i think you can do it with this as well

```
/root/*[not(name()='terminate')]
```

Comment: To select *all* the elements, anywhere in the document, use this: `//*[not(self::a)]`

Comment: "I cannot self terminate" =)

Answer (score 6):

If you are using XPath 2.0 you can use

```
/root/* except /root/terminate
```

Which does what you would expect. It matches for nodes that exist in the first sequence but not the second.

[XPath 2.0 Specification - except operator](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#doc-xpath-IntersectExceptExpr)