# XPath to get a full node except one child

Tags: xml, xpath, element

The idea is very similar to [the one asked about in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121539/xpath-to-get-all-child-elements-except-one-with-specific-name) and probably many others.

However, instead of extracting childs, I'm interested in the whole trimmed node. That is, the common solution is using

`//node/*[not(self::a)]`

instead of

`//node/*`

I'm looking for a way to apply the same logic of excluding a certain named branch, but extracting the node from a higher level: `//node` instead of `//node/*`.

What would be the appropriate syntax for this? `//node[not(//node/a)]` and similar doesn't seem to work.

**example:**

```
<root>
   <some_wrapper>
     <node>
       <a>
           <report key=1>
               <text>t</text>
           </report>
           <report key=2>
               <text>t</text>
           </report>
       </a>
       <b>
           <text>sample_text</text>
           <value>1</value>
       </b>
       <c>
           <text>sample_text</text>
           <value>2</value>
       </c>
     </node>
   </some_wrapper>
</root>
```

The goal is to find and select the whole `node` section, like when using `//node`, except that `a` child should not be included in the selection.

`//node/*[not(self::a)]` doesn't work, since it selects a list of childs in node, but not the whole node (if I'm using the terminology correctly).

Comment: Add sample markup and explain in concrete terms what elements you do and do not want to be selected given specified invariants grounded in your example.  Keep in mind that XPath is for selection, not manipulation or transformation.  XSLT may be needed, but you should clarify your question with an example.  Thank you.

Comment: @kjhughes thanks. Added the example, I hope it helps clarifying the question!

Comment: Yeah, from your title, that's where I thought you were going with this.  XPath generally selects what's present in the XML (and can apply some functions).  Once you start wanting to create new combinations, you're into transformation, the realm of XSLT.

Comment: @kjhughes Thanks, I'll look into XSLT. From a high-level perspective and not knowing how exactly does XML work on the low level, it does seem like just a selection. But it also makes sense that filtering the results may require some transformations.

Answer (score 2):

XPath always selects nodes that are present in the input document, unchanged. If you want to select a node named N, then //N will select that node; it returns, in effect, a reference to the node in the source document. If that node has children in the source document, then selecting it isn't going to remove those children.

Note that the XPath expression doesn't actually select the children. Many tools and applications that use XPath display the nodes selected by an XPath expression by serializing the whole XML subtree of those nodes, but that's a decision of the calling application (it could equally well display the result as a path containing the ancestors of the node, e.g. `/root[1]/someWrapper[1]/node[2]`.)

If you want to create a modified copy of part of the source document, you need XSLT or XQuery for that, not XPath.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the xpath to get all nodes (except the `a`) under `some_wrapper`.

```
//some_wrapper/descendant::*[not(name()='a' or ancestor::a)]
```

If you want to filter only the items under `node` tag then use the below.

```
//some_wrapper/descendant::*[not(name()='a' or ancestor::a) and (name()='node' or ancestor::node)]
```